# How to Block a thread on CPU then awaking it?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, cpu-usage, thread-synchronization

How to block a thread on CPU (So it doesn't use CPU time) and then awaking it after a time t without using **signal** mechanism.

Comment: If this is for synchronisation, have you tried using a for loop to make the thread look like it's blocked until a latter time?

Comment: yes , but in that case it'll be consuming cpu and I don't want it to use CPU time.

Comment: Can you expand on your question? What are you trying to achieve? What is your platform?

Comment: ^^ inter-thread comms is OS-specific.  Most relevant OS have events/semaphores, or maybe you can use the POSIX Threads library?

Comment: That's correct @Martin, right now I am using the same approach using POSIX threads and it's working but this implementation require **signaling** and hence not efficient with respect to time. So, I need very fast way ( in ns ).

Comment: I am implementing in Linux system where one thread should block on a variable(no cpu utilization) and other should execute and vice-versa.

Comment: ns, lol, shome joke shurely?

Comment: With general-purpose desktop OS, the best you will be able to do re. latency with kernel inter-thread signaling is a few us.   Without kernel signaling, you will burn both CPU and memory-bandwidth on spinlocks.  You cannot have both.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross platform way to do this, but a few options are:

Since you are doing this on Linux, your best option is the `pthread` library and  something like [`pthread_mutex_timedlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html)

Example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
struct timespec timeout;

timeout.tv_sec = 2; // Two seconds
timeout.nv_nsec = 0; // Zero nanoseconds
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); // Initialize mutex object
pthread_mutex_timedlock(&mutex, &timeout); // Wait for two seconds.
```

It is advised you check the return value of the functions for any errors that may have occurred.

---

If you really don't want to use any OS libraries, you can't put the thread to sleep, but you can use special instructions, such as `pause` or `rep; nop;` while spinning to reduce power consumption.

For example:

```
while (time(NULL) < timeToWake) asm("pause");
```